# Need to filter entire div content instead of just part of it

Tags: javascript

I have a script that filters content based on a string. However, it has to be that exact string and I can't figure out how to filter for a segment of the search string.

ex. If this worked there would be two results with the word "Pokemon"

```js
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('test');

for (let x = 0; x < divs.length; x++) {
  let div = divs[x];
  let content = div.innerHTML.trim();

  if (content !== 'Pokemon') {
    div.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  Pokemon
</div>
<div class="test">
  Handtekening
</div>
<div class="test">
  Thuis
</div>
```

Comment: Use `indexOf()` rather than equality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [`String.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method and check that the return value equals `-1` instead of using `!==`

```js
const hideElsIfNot = str => {
  let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
  for (let x = 0; x < divs.length; x++) {
    let div = divs[x];
    let content = div.innerHTML.trim();

    if (content.indexOf(str) === -1) {
      div.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
};

hideElsIfNot('Pokemon');
```

```html
<div class='test'>Pokemon</div>
<div class='test'>Digimon</div>
<div class='test'>Not Pokemon</div>
```

You can see from the example that any divs that contain the string "Pokemon" will not be hidden.

Comment: I'd recommend using the more semantic [String.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes). While it doesn't have IE support, the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Polyfill) for it is very small.